# Update different values into other tables in consequent way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario like one table contains 10000 rows with one column null. I have other table with different 5 id.

now I want to update table one with those different id like 1st row with 1st id, 2nd row with 2nd id, 3rd row with 3rd id, 4th row with 4th id,,5th row with 5th id, 6th row with 1st id, 7th row with 2nd id and so on.

```
 table1 sl   value
          ----------
         1    null
         2    null
         3    null
         4    null
         5    null
```

and so on

```
table 2 id_name names
            1     ram 
            2     sam
            3     jam
```

Now the result should
Table 1

```
  sl   value
      ----------
     1    ram
     2    sam
     3    jam
     4    ram
     5    sam
```

how can we achieve that.

Comment: You tagged 2008R2 and 2012 which version are you using?\

Comment: any version is okay for me

Comment: SQL treats all tables as *unordered* sets, so there is no implicit "first row". For that you need to use ORDER BY. Are you implying in your question that the first row is the row with the lowest value in `sl` and that `sl` is a unique key?

Comment: Pleae do not tag multiple versions. Please specify the One version you are Actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `row_number()` function to assign each row a row number the corresponds to the id of `table2`.

```
declare @table1 table (s1 int, [value] varchar(5));
declare @table2 table (id int, [value] varchar(5));

insert into @table1 (s1)
values
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),
(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

insert into @table2 (id, [value])
values
(1,'qwe'),
(2,'asd'),
(3,'zxc'),
(4,'yui'),
(5,'hjk');

with cte as (
    select s1, [value]
        , row_number() over (partition by ((s1-1)/5)+1 order by s1 asc) rn
    from @table1
)
update cte set [value] = (select t2.[value] from @table2 t2 where t2.id = rn);

select * from @table1;
```

Returns:

| s1 | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | qwe |
| 2 | asd |
| 3 | zxc |
| 4 | yui |
| 5 | hjk |
| 6 | qwe |
| 7 | asd |
| 8 | zxc |
| 9 | yui |
| 10 | hjk |

Note: If you provide DDL+DML as shown here you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Assumes there are no gaps in either table's id sequence. I'd prefer to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sl) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table2) + 1` rather than use `sl` in the PARTITION clause, for example.